# Is there a way to dynamically filter a data studio report?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a data studio report and I want to create a web app where the client can log in and see the data. I don’t want to duplicate my report for all the different clients, is there a way to do this without using filtering by email ?

I was thinking maybe there is a way to add parameters in the embed url ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can try using "filter for email" option. This allows you to set up reports filtered as per your clients email.
https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713766?hl=en